# Is it safe to register Key-Value observation on the same keypath of the same object using the same observer multiple times?

Tags: objective-c

I have a piece of code that might trigger the same registration process twice. It's fairly contrived so I'd rather not to have a way to manually check if the registration has happened. But if registering the same KVO relationship is not allowed multiple times can someone suggest a way of detecting if an object has already been registered with another observer for a certain keypath effectively?

Answer (score 2):

Its safe. Your

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

will just get called multiple times. If you dont want that you could try to remove the observer, before adding it again.

Comment: Thanks! That saves me lots of efforts from checking